# SQL Server : how to use variable tablename from select value

Tags: sql-server

```
 SELECT
 (
     SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Volume,0))
       FROM Order_【a1.Login】
      WHERE Login = a1.Login
 ) AS SelfVolume
 FROM dbo.Account a1
```

I want the table name in the sub-select (【a1.Login】) to match the value `a1.Login` from the outer select statement (field `Login` of table `Account`). How can I get this result?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a really bad database schema if you store the same type of information in different tables for different accounts?

Comment: I also think this is a bad database schema, but now there is such a demand must be done, mssql statement there is no way to achieve like this function?    I tried to use function, procduce, but I still can not afford to solve this problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **technical answer** is: By using dynamic SQL. It's complicated, error-prone and potentially dangerous (beware of Bobby Tables). Your SQLs will become unreadable and unmaintainable. You are entering a world of pain.

The **correct answer** is: You don't. Don't create a separate Orders table for every user. Create *one* Orders table with a foreign key to your Account table.

---

If you still want to go ahead and work with this broken database design (remember: You are entering a world of pain, and you are just getting started), you will somehow need to construct the following SQL dynamically:

```
 SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Login_Volume,0)) FROM
 (
     SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Volume,0)) AS Login_Volume FROM Order_SomeUser WHERE Login = 'SomeUser'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Volume,0)) AS Login_Volume FROM Order_SomeOtherUser WHERE Login = 'SomeOtherUser'
     UNION ALL
     ...
 ) AS AllSums
```

You can do that in the language of your choice, either in your target language (C#, Java, PHP, etc.), which is probably the easiest and most maintainable solution, or directly in T-SQL, by using T-SQL cursors and loops (= the hard way). Whichever language you choose, the algorithm is straight-forward:

- Loop through your `Account` table and get the `Login`s.

  - [Sanitize the value](https://xkcd.com/327/) and validate that the corresponding `Order_` table exists.
  - Create one SQL statement for each account.
  - Join them with `UNION ALL`.
- Wrap them in the outer `SELECT` as shown above.

Again: If there is *any* chance of fixing your broken DB design instead, do that, it *will* pay off in the long run.

Comment: I also think this is a bad database schema, but now there is such a demand must be done, mssql statement there is no way to achieve like this function?    I tried to use function, procduce, but I still can not afford to solve this problem

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely. 
As you said, now only through the use of the cursor, CTE to achieve the results I want.